# How to create Image in runtime in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I am trying to create custom menu which consists of text at least 2 textblock in one rectangle, which will act as button, For that purpose, May be converting the text into Image may be good idea to implement and serve my purpose to. so I want and Idea or code to create image during runtime, any suggestion ? If you have any sample code or link to refer??

Comment: What do u mean by  create Image in runtime ??? Are u tying to change source of image ?

Answer (score 0):

if by "2 textblock in one rectangle" you mean text in two lines then try this

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
         <TextBlock Text="DEF"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```